# What's the precision of a quartz crystal?

Tags: oscillator, datasheet, crystal, pll, tolerance

Crystal datasheets usually list the following parameters:

> - The Frequency Tolerance of a crystal is defined as the allowable
>     deviation from the specified Frequency when measured at 25°C or room
>     temperature.
> - The Frequency Stability is defined as the allowable deviation over the
>     rated temperature range.

In the context of precision vs accuracy, how should I interpret the *Frequency Tolerance*?

If I take two consecutive measurements of **the same** crystal assuming constant temperature. Can I expect the frequency error to be the same on both measurements (or at least lower than the Frequency Tolerance)? Or should both measured errors be assumed independent?

---

I'm analyzing the accuracy bounds of a GPSDO built with a MCU's PWM peripheral. The Idea is to avoid the need of a VCO if the required time-base quality is achieved. Slow frequency drift changes would be manageable through an FLL loop, so the distinction is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequency tolerance vs Frequency stability...

**Tolerance** involves mostly the making of a crystal blank: grinding, and plating its surface so that its static primary resonance hits the target frequency. Tolerance is spec'd at a fixed temperature, because temperature mostly affects resonance stability. Tolerance of primary resonant frequency is the least-complex spec. Tolerance might include ageing. Or how a crystal ages might be a separate spec (also done at a fixed temperature).

**Stability** involves mostly temperature. Temperature stability is complicated by rate-of-change of temperature - fast changes of temperature can change resonant frequency radically if one part of the crystal cools/heats more than another part. The crystal spec sheet usually addresses a very slowly-scanned temperature range where the crystal-under-test is uniformly heated. Fast-changing temperature effects are affected by how a crystal is mounted - something over which a crystal manufacturer has no control.

Crystals are usually cut at specific angles where temperature coefficients are near zero. But they remain close-to-zero over a very small range of temperatures. An AT-cut crystal extends this range somewhat because temperature profiles follow a 3rd-order curve. Over the specified temperature range, the derivative of this curve **changes sign** at two different temperatures. Changing the cut angle very slightly allows a manufacturer to tailor the stability of resonance to a different temperature range.
 Other crystal cuts follow a 2nd-order temperature curve, where perfect temperature/frequency stability occurs at only one temperature.

A crystal manufacturer can only specify a crystal's primary resonance, preferably its *series resonance:* the frequency where its mass and spring-constant match. But many crystal oscillating circuits also involve the *circuit + crystal capacitance*, which shifts the crystal's *series resonance* to a higher frequency. To accommodate circuit-builders, a manufacturer may specify a crystals' *parallel resonance*, and include a capacitance in this spec. Ideally, this added capacitance is not affected by temperature.

You seem to be mostly concerned with frequency stability...measured over a long time-span. A **frequency counter** or a **clock, watch** is an example. An oscillator's jitter is not a concern in such an application.

By varying an oscillator's capacitance, its oscillating frequency can be changed over a small range. Doing so usually affects frequency stability detrimentally, partly because the added capacitance isn't temperature-stable, and partly because sharpness of resonance is compromised when shifted from series-resonance. A crystal manufacturer's spec sheet cannot address this added complication.
A manufacturer has the difficulty of specifying a crystal that might be used in a few different application circuits (mostly oscillators) of widely-varying topologies. A casual oscillator design will very likely result in frequency variations poorer than the raw crystal spec.

TLDR:

> If I take two consecutive measurements of the same crystal assuming
>   constant temperature. Can I expect the frequency error to be the same
>   on both measurements (or at least lower than the Frequency Tolerance)?
>   Or should both measured errors be assumed independent?

I'm assuming that you're measuring frequency of an oscillator using a single crystal to set its frequency, and you're using exactly the same measurement setup for both measurements, using a frequency counter having much better specs than the crystal-under-test. Also assuming that the whole test oscillator operates at the "constant temperature":
About the only crystal spec that can vary is its ageing spec.

Should you put the same crystal into a different oscillator for the 2nd measurement, expect frequency tolerance of the oscillator frequency to be greater than tolerance of the raw crystal. A crystal driven with more current shifts in frequency too...rarely spec'd in a crystal data sheet.
The components of an oscillator likely vary, for example its DC supply voltage. And you didn't mention a varying load - that will pull frequency +/-... so a 2nd frequency counter (having excellent specs) might measure a different frequency than the 1st.
 The components of an oscillator might have their own ageing effects. A freshly-built oscillator often drifts more while very young, and improves with age. A long rest-period between two frequency measurements is affected by both crystal ageing, and oscillator ageing.

Comment: Thanks glen. *I'm assuming that you're measuring frequency [...]*. I'd need a clarification on this. Do you mean that in this theatical experiment the only varying spec would be aging and the measured frequency would be the same? Or both measurements would exhibit a random error within the frequency tolerance? Disregarding aging, of course.

Comment: We're mostly interested in a crystal oscillator's frequency. Ageing affects frequency. You'd be looking for a drift of frequency over time, beyond random frequency errors. Read about *Allan variance*. You'd be comparing your drifting crystal oscillator against the excellent *frequency counter's* internal timebase. "Drift" is far, far slower than the oscillation period. Crystal oscillators often have least frequency drift over periods of seconds-to-hours...beyond that, ageing effects dominate. Time periods of seconds or shorter are temp-related. Shorter than that gets into "jitter" territory.

Answer (score 2):

If your crystal oscillator(amplifier) is internal to a microcontroller, you will have horrid short term Time_Jitter because of trash on the substrate, the Ground and the VDD.

This trash will be program_execution dependent.

Are you prepared to SHUT OFF THE MCU, during your precision measurements?

==================================

MCUs use a PI_filter interface circuit between the external XTAL + 2 small capacitors, and the on_silicon linear amplifier that excites the XTAL initially and then slowly adds energy through the PI_filter interface, to build and build the voltage swing that is the outward evidence of Quartz Stored Energy.

The primary node of Jitter Vulnerability is the input to the circuit that converts sinusoid_from_the_PI_interface to Square wave.

That circuit is on_silicon, and all the trash I mentioned will act to upset the precision time event of the zero crossing of the sinusoid.

Simply estimate the SlewRate of the sinusoid, assuming 1 volt Peak signal, and assume 0.5 volt of trash.

Then use

- Tjitter = Vnoise/SlewRate
- Tjitter = 0.5v / 63,000,000  in this example

as estimate of your Time Jitter for 10MHz circuit that squares the sinusoid, using on_silicon limiting amplifier.

Notice that is about 8 nanoSeconds.

The math and the concept is good.

The only variable is the level of trash.

==================================

How will you "measure" the frequency?

Hewlett_Packard introduced a Time_Frequency Measurement Counter back about 1970; the machine only had a 10MHz internal reference but used charge-storage at beginning and ending of the measurement interval, for an analog interpolation of the device_under_test period with 1 nanosecond time resolution.

This was on a large automated test set for production testing of military radios; the ability to measure frequency "accurately" in just 0.1second dwell time was a big part of production efficiency.

Do you need such a interpolation-machine for your measurement?

Comment: I've never seen a crystal oscillator built into an MCU. They're always (at least that I've seen) RC-based oscillators.

Comment: By crystal oscillator amplifier, do you mean the MCU PLL? I'm aware that generating a disciplined clock from a higher frequency one will have an awful jitter. I'm analyzing it's impact on my measurements.

Comment: Many (most) MCUs have two pins that you connect to an external crystal to generate the clock - internal to the MCU is just an amplifier that makes the crystal oscillate. In smaller MUCs that clock may be used directly more sophisticated ones will have a PLL to generate a higher clock frequency than you can do directly with a crystal.

Comment: Thanks, this is really interesting. For my application, jitter will only matters as long as I can bound the frequency tolerance. If I only can assume that an XO with 30ppm frequency tolerance can drift 30us per second, jitter in the order of ns won't matter.